# Why is `SigmoidBinaryCrossEntropyLoss` in `DJL` implemented this way?

Tags: objective-functions, loss, sigmoid, binary-crossentropy

[SigmoidBinaryCrossEntropyLoss](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/api/src/main/java/ai/djl/training/loss/SigmoidBinaryCrossEntropyLoss.java) implementation in DJL accepts two kinds of outputs from NNs:

1. where `sigmoid` activation has already been applied.
2. where raw NN output is taken as is.

The choice is determied by [fromSigmoid](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/api/src/main/java/ai/djl/training/loss/SigmoidBinaryCrossEntropyLoss.java#L50) parameter.

Here's how (1) `fromSigmoid=true` [looks like](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/api/src/main/java/ai/djl/training/loss/SigmoidBinaryCrossEntropyLoss.java#L72-L75):

```
loss =
      epsLog(pred)
      .mul(lab)
      .add(epsLog(NDArrays.sub(1., pred)).mul(NDArrays.sub(1., lab)));
```

And here's how (2) `fromSigmoid=false` [looks like](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/api/src/main/java/ai/djl/training/loss/SigmoidBinaryCrossEntropyLoss.java#L67-L70):

```
loss =
      Activation.relu(pred)
      .sub(pred.mul(lab))
      .add(Activation.softPlus(pred.abs().neg()));
```

The logic behind (1) `fromSigmoid=true` branch looks like a standard cross entropy loss implementation, but I fail to understand why (2) `fromSigmoid=false` is implemented the way it is.

For instance, why is there no `sigmoid` application, why is there `relu` later followed by `softPlus`? I'd like to understand what does (2) do and what's the theory behind its implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got answered at https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/discussions/2087#discussioncomment-3955290, derivation for (2) formula are available at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L100-L136.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).